# Calling Server from Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, api, client-side

I have currently have created an API that connects to a MongoDb database and I am now trying to call it from a Javascript client. I have already tried multiple ways of calling it but none of them have worked so far so I am looking for some guidance on how to make it work. My latest attempt has been using the JQuery library:

`$.get("https://myurl:8080/api", function(data) {
            alert('Load was performed');
        });`

I found that the server acknowledges all my calls to it but for some reason, doesn't return any JSON response as I am expecting.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are the domains the same between the server and the client? If not, you'll need to include the appropriate CORS headers on the server-side.

Comment: I think this might be my problem, I am using cloud9 to do this so I think it might have CORS disabled? Because everything I do returns an error. How would I include CORS headers server side?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://myurl:8080/api',
   data: {
      format: 'json'
   },
   error: function() {
     // your code
   },
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data) {
    //your code
   },
   type: 'GET'
});
```

It should work.

Comment: This is once again calling the api but returning an error instead of a success. I have tested my api using postman so I know it is capable of handling and processing requests fine, is there a way to extract more information about the error?

Comment: use error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     // your code
   },

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery function `getJson` :

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "https://myurl:8080/api", function(data) {
  console.log( "success" );
  alert('Load was performed');

})
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });
```